# Hive add partition with ACL

Tags: hive, acl

I am facing some problems with hive partition creation where the  permissions user has in hdfs are acl based.

1. I created a normal user in linux.

2. I gave him permissions recursively on a directory which is referred to by an external table.
(e.g. hdfs dfs -setfacl -R -m default:user:newUserName:rwx /apps/dbname/tblname)
I checked to see the permissions are recursively applied and I can read and write to the
directory even though I do not have any POSIX related permissions on the same. i.e. I only have the ACLS.

1. I logged in as newUserName and started hive and ran an "alter table add partition" command, where the location for the partition is /apps/dbname/tablename/somefolder
2. hive responds with the error: Authorization failed: java.security.AccessControlException: action WRITE not permitted on path hdfs://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8020/apps/dbname/tblname for user newUserName. Use SHOW GRANT to get more details.

What am I missing here. dfs.namenode.acls.enabled is true. I thought that was all that was required for ACLs to work. I am using hortonworks hdp2.1
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In current version of hive (0.13.x) Support for HDFS ACL (introduced in Apache Hadoop 2.4) is yet to be added.

Please find below jira which addresses the above issue:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7714